# How to connect MS ACCESS DB with my asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, database

I am trying to connect my MS Access Db with my asp.net website. When I run my code(on localhost only) it does not show any error or exception but it just wait for server to response.
I am following code :

```
 string connection = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; datasource=I:/Adittya/test.accdb";

        string query = "select * from test";
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(dr);

        testGrid.DataSource = dt;
        testGrid.DataBind();
```

One more thing my DB is in my pen-drive whose location is static.

Do I have problem with my code or we cannot connect to DB present in pen-drive.

Comment: Mr. Janjua kept editing his answer based on my suggestions to you. and then submitted the working copy. he edited thrice. I think, you need to do justice when marking the answer. Thanks

Comment: read my below comment. You have not said a single time that the connection is missing etc. Read your comments again yourself.Your focus is only on the connection string. Thanks.

Comment: @AtharAnis yes you talk about command object but I have not seen your comments, bcz they are hidden. I created a test db on MS Access and ran her code on my PC and found the exact errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try your data source as

```
datasource=I:\\Adittya\\test.accdb
```

Comment: Also try to add Persist Security Info = False in your connection string

Comment: and Jet OLEDB:Database Password=yourpassword; too

Comment: I tried your solution but gain no success. I am still on previous position.

Comment: ok , tell me how are u creating ur connection string? you typed it ? or did you use a wizard to copy it? I am sure it is your connection string thats causing problem

Comment: Your connection string should be like, "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; datasource=I:\\Adittya\\test.accdb"; Persist Security Info = false;

Comment: I have typed it but I have also checked its connectivity through server explorer and tested it there its showing 'Test Connection Succeed'

Comment: if it succeeded using the server explorer, then we need to look into other reasons. did you try to copy that file from pen drive to local drive like C: and then connecting it?

Comment: i think i have got what the problem is :-) OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(con); <===ADD CON
You have not specified the connection in the Command. You need to tell the command what connection it has to use.

Comment: did u open the connection after you added my solution?   did u do something like con.open();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13544/discussion-between-athar-anis-and-adittya)

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem in your code, You have not set the connection to the command object and also not open the connection.Below code is working for me. Try this

```
    string connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\Test1.accdb";

    string query = "select * from [Table]";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connection);
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();     
    cmd.CommandText = query;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    con.Close();
    testGrid.DataSource = dt;
    testGrid.DataBind();
```

or Try this solution Using SqlDataSource

Example:I have created a test Acess database and I used Sql datasource it is working fine. Try this solution

```
<connectionStrings>       
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Test1.accdb"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$     ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

It is working fine for me.

Comment: why are u editing your answers based on my suggestions? u just added the command connection after i suggested it in my answer. How unfair is that?

Comment: @AtharAnis I had only seen you connection string but it is not the answer. You have not said that the Connection is not open or set. I ran this code on my PC and When I debug I found that the Connection command is not set to the command object and Connection is also not open. I have not read your any comment except the connection string answer. And i'm editing my anser bcz I have done it on my PC and and I have to copy the code from there

Comment: I have tried your code too, it is also not working when I am running the code but when I check it on visual studio it works fine there.

Comment: Both of the above codes worked, I test it on my PC using Visual Studio and MS Access

Comment: Voted up for efforts and a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
     "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Database/TestDB.mdb"))
```